# Why does this binary search tree cause a stack overflow?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
/*main  idea  is to construct ordered statistic tree,which is  similar of
binary search tree,width addition of  one key,which shows us it's rank in given  
tree,for this i introduced additional one key-rank
*/
struct node
{
    int val;
    node *left,*right;
    int rank;
    node(int t) { val=t;left=right=NULL;}


};
node *root;
void insert(node *p,int ele)
{
    if(p==NULL){
        p=new node(ele);
        return ;


    }
    else if(ele<p->val)
    {
        insert(p->left,ele);

    }
    else if(ele>p->val)
    {
        insert(p->right,ele);

    }

}
void inorder (node *p)
{
    if(p!=NULL){ inorder(p->left);
    cout<<p->val<<" "<<p->rank;
    inorder(p->right);
    }

}
int count_node(node *t)
{
    int sum=0;
    if(t==NULL) return 0;
    else sum=1;
    if(t->left) sum+=count_node(t->left);
    if(t->right) sum+=count_node(t->right);
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    root=NULL;
    root->rank=0;
    insert(root,26);
    insert(root,17);
    insert(root,41);
    insert(root,14);
    insert(root,30);
    insert(root,21);
    insert(root,47);
    insert(root,10);
    insert(root,16);
    insert(root,28);
    insert(root,38);
    insert(root,35);
    insert(root,39);
    insert(root,19);
    insert(root,21);
    insert(root,20);
    insert(root,7);
    insert(root,12);
    insert(root,3);
    inorder(root);

    return 0;
}
```

This code causes an overflow, but I do not understand why, because I have constructed the constructor properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is:

```
root=NULL;
root->rank=0;
```

this cause **undefined behavior** because you dereference a `NULL` pointer. Anything can happen.

Also:

```
void insert(node *p,int ele)
{
    if(p==NULL){
        p=new node(ele);
        return ;


    }
    //...
}
```

This doesn't modify the original pointer. If you call `insert` on a `NULL` pointer, it will be `NULL` when the function returns. You need to pass it by reference:

```
void insert(node *& p,int ele)
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Luchian said, you also have this problem:

```
void insert(node *p,int ele)
{
    if(p==NULL){
        p=new node(ele);
        return ;
    }
....
```

where the pointer `p` is passed by value. When you say `p=...` you are changing a copy of the pointer that is only visible to the function. You might want a [reference](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#overview-refs) to the pointer you're changing:

```
void insert(node *&p, int ele){ ... }
```

Comment: so  how to  call insert method in main part?

Comment: If you pass it by [reference](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html#faq-8.1) (with the '&' in the function signature), you call it as before, and the compiler makes sure to give the function the address of the `root` variable and not just its value (initially, `NULL`).

Answer (score 1):

You have a very big issue the first two lines of your `main` function:

```
root=NULL;
root->rank=0;
```

If you look at your own definition above, the `root` is defined as a *node pointer*, that is it does not reserve any space for an actual node.

If you do not reserve the space yourself, than you are trying to write through uninitialized memory. What's more, you *explicitly say* that the root points to *nothing*, that is `NULL`. And in the very next line, you try to access it's member called `rank`.

You should try replacing the line:

```
root = NULL;
```

With

```
root = new node(0);
```

or something similar that actually reserves the space and constructs a node.

Alternatively, you could try assinging the rank to the root in the very end, since you `insert` function actually constructs the root if it is not present. **edit** as Luchian said, you only *try* to construct the root in the `insert` method. If you re-write the insert method in the way he has suggested, than it might all work if you just move the `root->rank=0;` line to the end of the insertion process.

Answer (score 0):

```
root=NULL;
root->rank=0;
```

This could be the problem, you should not deference a `NULL` object.

Comment: yes but i can't print values ,i have changed it,but still does not work

Comment: hopefully you have changed to created an object of type `node` using `new`. What is the error you get now?